# How do I call a Method from another file in OnCommand of my asp:Button? asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to tidy up my Default.aspx and tried to move the 'actionlistener' (I know that might not be the right name in C#) of my buttons into a file I've called 'DefaultCodeBehind.cs'.

I declared the CodeBehind file on top of Default.aspx like so:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="DefaultCodeBehind.cs" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

This is the button (also in Default.aspx):

```
<asp:Button runat="server" type="button" id="contSec5" CommandName="contSec5" OnCommand="ToggleDivPage" CssClass="button_menubar" text="Section 5" />
```

And this is the actionlistener/method in DefaultCodeBehind.cs:

```
void ToggleDivPage(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    code...
}
```

This is the error appearing when trying to execute the code:

> CS1061: 'default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'ToggleDivPage' and no extension method 'ToggleDivPage' accepting a first argument of type 'default_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I also tried to call the method like so:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" type="button" id="contSec5" CommandName="contSec5" OnCommand="DefaultCodeBehind.ToggleDivPage" CssClass="button_menubar" text="Section 5" />
```

But I wasn't really expecting this to work anyway. (I'm pretty new to C# and especially to asp.net, what might explain this funny attempt.)

Do I have to declare CodeBehind different or isn't it even possible to move the actionlisteners outside Default.aspx.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Lars

Comment: I think it's searching the method in `CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"`

Comment: You have both `CodeFile` and `CodeBehind` specified - I think you need to relook at the overall structure of your project, as it's rather odd to have both.  If the error were just talking about DefaultCodeBehind, I'd suggest you need to make `ToggleDivPage` either `protected` or `public` - right now it'll be `private` and inaccessible from the page.

Comment: @Stefan Actually I just discovered this myself. An it is working. But thank you anyway!

Comment: You may want to consider static classes as well. It's always an option but it depends on how you want to use them.

Comment: @James Thorpe I complitly overlooked the CodeFile tag. ToggleDivPage is public now also. Thank you too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several minutes after I posted this question, I stumbled upon the answer myself. I completely overlooked the `CodeFile` tag. Therefore `ToggleDivPage` couldn't be found in `CodeBehind`, because it had to be in `Default.aspx.cs`. Moving it and of course making it `public` solved my problem. A thanks to @Stefan and @James Thorpe who solved the problem as well.